# overlay shadow_hand

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody.

someone know , how to do an overlay of shadow_robot?

i need make some changes to sr_hand description of urdf's files.

thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53311/overlay-shadow_hand/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be done as any overlay. There's a tutorial which is probably helpful here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1